# poedit workaround for dynamic gettext

Tags: php, internationalization, gettext, poedit

I have started using gettext for translating text and messages i send to user.
I am using poedit as an editor, but i am struggling with dynamic messages.

For example i have things like the login where i have a variable that tells the type of error.

```
$this->translate('page-error-' . $error);
```

When i auto update from poedit this gets read like "page-error-".
What i do is have a file where i place dummy calls to the translate method with all the possible keys to have them added in my poedit when auto updating.

I don't particularly like this situation.
How do you guys do it.

Thanks for your ideas

Comment: I could not understand the problem. can you describe it more clear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No -- this is not possible, because the editor (and the `gettext` tools) are reading your sources, not executing your program. You'll have to keep the dummy calls or add the keys to the translation files yourself.

Comment: how can i add keys manually ? i wasnt able to find a way. Also are those manuallly keys removed when doing a sync with sources ?

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying something like

```
$this->translate(sprintf('page-error-%s', $error));
```

Comment: how i make the dinamic keys is not the problem, the problem is how you add them in poedit.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem.

for example i have

in php

```php
//Gives FORM_HEADER_ADD or FORM_HEADER_EDIT
echo $this->translate('FORM_HEADER_' . strtoupper($this->data));
```

When i sync with poedit it will pick up 'FORM_HEADER_' which is not a identifier i have (generated) in the code.

So i had to fix the problem my giving Poedit full identifiers i solved that by doing the following in php

```php
echo ($this->data === 'add') ? $this->translate('FORM_HEADER_ADD') : $this->translate('FORM_HEADER_EDIT');
```

UPDATE!

I kept looking into this problem. And i currently gave up importing from source. This is how i continue until i find a better solution

1. Build application and use as many static identifiers as possible.
2. Enable logging of untranslated (dynamic) identifiers

   ```php
   protected function _initMyTranslate(){

       $date = new Zend_Date();
       $fileName = sprintf('/../logs/translation_%1$s.log', $date->toString('dd-MM'));

       $writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(APPLICATION_PATH . $fileName);
       $log    = new Zend_Log($writer);

       // get the translate resource from the ini file and fire it up
       $resource = $this->getPluginResource('translate');
       $translate = $resource->getTranslate();

       // add the log to the translate
       $translate->setOptions(
               array(
                   'log'             => $log,
                   'logUntranslated' => true
               )
           );

       // return the translate to get it in the registry and so on
       return $translate;
   }
   ```
3. Use Poedit to sync with source and translate the strings that are found.
4. During testing/debugging phase check the log for untranslated strings.
5. Add the untranslated strings to the .po file.

   ```
   msgid "IDENTIFIER"
   msgstr "TRANSLATION STRING"
   ```
6. Open po file and save it to create the mo file (DO NOT SYNC WITH SOURCE OR ALL IS LOST).

UPDATE 2.

I now use a seperate file for my manual identifiers , by using a text editor (gedit/notepad). Now i have two files:

1. Auto generated by poedit called <language>.po
2. manually editted file called <language>_manual.po

i configured my translate in application.ini to scan for all files in the language directory

```ini
resources.translate.adapter = gettext
resources.translate.content = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/languages/"
resources.translate.locale = auto ;use en to force english or nl for dutch..etc
resources.translate.scan = directory
resources.translate.options.disableNotices = false
```

if you want to translate into another language in poedit do file -> new catalog from POT file, and start translating your manually added strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a finite number of errors, you can add some dummy code inside a `if (false)` condition, whose sole purpose is to have PoEdit pick up the translations.

For example:

```
if (false) {
  _('role_visitor');
  _('role_hiker_reader');
  _('role_hiker');
  _('role_translator');
  _('role_proofreader');
  _('role_moderator');
  _('role_moderator_2');
  _('role_moderator_3');
  _('role_admin');
}
```

You can then translate with:

```
$translated_role = _('role_' . $role);
```

Credits to: http://eng.marksw.com/2012/12/05/how-to-expose-dynamic-translatable-text-to-translation-tools-like-poedit/