# Where to translate message strings - in the view or in the model?

Tags: language-agnostic, internationalization, gettext, xgettext

We have a multilingual (PHP) application and use gettext for i18n. There are a few classes in the backend/model that return messages or message formats for printf().

We use xgettext to extract the strings that we want to translate.

We apply the gettext function T_() in the frontend/view - this seems to be where it belongs. So far we kept the backend clean from T_() calls, this way we can also unit-test messages.

So in the frontend we have something like

```
echo T_($mymodel->getMessage());
```

or

```
printf(T_($mymodel->getMessageFormat()), $mymodel->getValue());
```

This makes it impossible to apply xgettext to extract the strings, unless we put some dummy T_("my message %s to translate") call in the MyModel class.

So this leads to the more general question:

**Do you apply translation in the backend classes, resp. where do you apply translation and how do you keep track of the strings which you have to translate?**

(I am aware of [Question: poedit workaround for dynamic gettext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873017/).)

Answer (score 1):

My backend classes usually output english strings with parameters left out. Example

```
["Good job %s you have %i points", "Paul", 10]
```

Then the key for the translation is the English string (since I don't really like message codes).

Comment: This is pretty much the way we do it. How do you keep track of the strings like "Good job %s you have %i points" to be translated?

Comment: Often times we surround the text by <!>Text</!> so it makes grepping it easier, and then do a global replace on <!> and </!> at the translation API level.

Answer (score 0):

Translation is for me totally a View issue except for clearly defined business reasons, like having to store displayed messages as shown. The latter could e.g. happen if you want to store a sent invoice as delivered to the client.